# Flutter dart handling json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

How can I map this data in flutter/ dart

```
[{
  "Genesis": {
  "1": "31",
  "2": "25",
  "3": "24",
  "4": "26",
  "5": "32",
  "6": "22",
  "7": "24",
  "8": "22",
  "9": "29",
  ...},
"Exodus":{
  "1": "22",
  "2": "25",
  "3": "22",
  "4": "31",
  "5": "23",
  "6": "30",
  "7": "25",
  "8": "32",
  "9": "35",
  "10": "29",
  "11": "10",
  "12": "51",
 ....} ...}]
```

Working with Bible JSON, I would like to get the words store them under string book, then store the keys in a list called chapters (for now not so interested in the value) only interested in how I can get the book and chapter from this JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to encode and decode json: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#decoding-and-encoding-json

I've created a simple example, how you can reach each element:

```dart
final sourceList = [{
  "Genesis": {
  "1": "31",
  "2": "25",
  "3": "24",
  "4": "26",
  "5": "32",
  "6": "22",
  "7": "24",
  "8": "22",
  "9": "29",
  },
"Exodus":{
  "1": "22",
  "2": "25",
  "3": "22",
  "4": "31",
  "5": "23",
  "6": "30",
  "7": "25",
  "8": "32",
  "9": "35",
  "10": "29",
  "11": "10",
  "12": "51",
 }}];
  
  final sourceMap = sourceList.first; // If sourceList.length == 1, otherwise you can iterate throught the list - https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html
  
  final books = sourceMap.keys; // If sourceList.length > 1, then do it inside forEach
  
  for (var book in books) {
    print(book);
    print(sourceMap[book]);
  }
  
  //You can do whatever you need - print(sourceMap['Exodus']['4']); prints `31`
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the map for this JSON so if your JSON grows, you should use the list for complex search.

You can use like this:

```
final model = books.firstWhere((item) => item.name == name);
```

If I were, I create a book model and  I would fill model in JSON file.

```
class BookModel {
  String name;
  Book book;
  BookModel(this.name, this.book);
}
```

And I created a sample to use in a flutter, look at this.
[Book Models Sample](https://gist.github.com/VB10/28873886fd67776beb494954b9db6e55)